# HTML Bootstrap Grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="container">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="background-color:blue">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:orange">

    <div align="center" style="background-color:pink">
    <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <h3>JOHN</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-default" role="navigation" style="background-color:purple">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
        <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Published</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Bookmarked</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow">
    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
    <table id="personal-information" class="table" align="left">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Joined:</td>
    <td>2018-02-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Last Active:</td>
    <td>2019-10-15 12:15:17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td>
    <td>MALE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>About me:</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

  </div>        

<div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="background-color:blue" >
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBswR.png)

I cleaned it up as much as possible. I also added colors to each div so it's clear to see.

I divided up my page into 4. 2 of them called sidenavs to create spaces on both sides to center view my main content, 1 is for the user image, name and nav buttons and the other one is for other content like personal info and will probably add more. So i divided them respectively: 1 - 2 -8 - 1

My problem is that, i don't understand the current alignment of my columns, As you can see from the image, side nav blue which should be at the right edge is now at the bottom. I made sure that all my columns sizes add up to 12 which is the maximum so i don't know why the other div is pushed down to the next row.

P.S. all those weird html names like sidenav even though it's not a navigation bar which is on the side. And the row content with an already div container. I copy pasted whole html page code from free bootstrap template(you can actually see the resemblance if you downloaded some of them - i'm not good at deciding how to design my pages so i just decided to pick from a template and tweak it however i want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this how it's meant to look?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="background-color:blue">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:orange">

      <div align="center" style="background-color:pink">
        <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="padding-top:10px;">
        <h3>JOHN</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-default" role="navigation" style="background-color:purple">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
          <li><a href="">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Published</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Bookmarked</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:yellow">
      <h3>Personal Information</h3>
      <table id="personal-information" class="table" align="left">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Joined:</td>
            <td>2018-02-10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Last Active:</td>
            <td>2019-10-15 12:15:17</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gender:</td>
            <td>MALE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td>26</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>About me:</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="background-color:blue">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

If so, you had

```
<div class="col-sm-1 sidenav" style="background-color:blue"></div>
```

Outside of

```
 <div class="row content"></div>
```

See here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v1bjec9/)

Comment: I'm not really familiar with visual studio code 2017. Is there any extension in the community with a html tag tracker? like if i click on an open tag, it will automatically tell me which is its closing tag? 

This page is just the simplest page of my website that is easiest to clean up, i still have to clean up other more complex page and  judging from this one(not to mention, i cleaned it up first before posting here) it seems to me that my html looks the way it is by accident and not by design/code.

Comment: Have a look at these: https://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/ and https://validator.w3.org/ . These will validate your HTML.

Comment: Also give this plugin a go: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag